# Remove auto size values from an image url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the **`-960x330`** part from the end of this image url and I tried it with with this jQuery:

```
jQuery("#the-team").each(function(){
    var img_url = jQuery(this).find("#the-team img").attr("src");
    var main_url = img_url.split('-960x330');
    var exact_url = main_url[0] + main_url[1]; 
    jQuery(this).find("#the-team img").attr("src" , exact_url );
});
```

Here's the html if anybody is unable to check the image.

```
<img alt="" width="960" height="330" src="http://phpyouth.com/clients/LawPoint/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Team-lawpoint-960x330.jpg">
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the media library for that wordpress site?  If so you could just rename the file in the media libary and remove it that way.

Comment: It isn't that way.  It's a hardcoded theme feature that resizes image according to the layout of the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery(this).find("#the-team img")` - means searching for `#the-team img` inside `#the-team`.
You need just `jQuery(this).find("img")`:

```
jQuery("#the-team").each(function(){
  var img_url = jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src");
  var main_url = img_url.split('-960x330');
  var exact_url = main_url[0] + main_url[1]; 
  jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src" , exact_url );
});
```

---

**EDIT**: A bit shorter:

```
jQuery("#the-team").each(function() {
  var img = jQuery(this).find("img");
  img.attr("src", img.attr("src").replace("-960x330", ""));
});
```

---

**FYI**: Not related to the issue, but worth mentioning. This line

```
jQuery("#the-team").each(function(){
```

suggests that you have more than one element on your page with the same *id*, which is incorrect. Element *id*-s should be unique. If you need them for styling, then `class` is the thing you want to use.

Comment: This works, but some explanation would help to educate the OP and any future visitors

Comment: @aquaman, is there a shorter solution to my problem(with or without jQuery)?